# Yii1 Detail View , how to add class to image

Tags: php, yii, detailview

I am using yii1 and facing problem in adding class to image shown in detail view , tell me how to add css class or static property to image to make width and height 40px;
my detail view code is below

```
   <?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
    'data' => $model,
    'attributes' => array(
        'id',
        'title',
        array(
            'label' => 'image',
            'type' => 'image',
            'value' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/images/foodcategory/' 

.$model->image ,
            ),
        'status',
        'created_at',
        'created_by',
        'modified_at',
        'modified_by',
    ),
));
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the type to `raw`. You can then add it using [`CHtml::image()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#image-detail):

```
array(
    'label' => 'image',
    'type' => 'raw',
    'value' => CHtml::image(
        Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/images/foodcategory/'.$model->image,
        'Alt text',
        array('class' => 'myclass') //and other html tag attributes
    ),
),
```

Comment: Or you can set the type to `'html'`, it's more representative.

Comment: I've had issues with `html` before hence `raw`. But if it works for the OP, go ahead.

Comment: What kind of issues if I may ask?

Comment: I can't remember the question, but I had recommended HTML in a similar answer. On running tests, the output was not correct. `raw` worked though.

Answer (score 0):

```
[
    'attribute'=>'image_url',
    'type' => 'image',
    'value'=> \Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl.'/'.$model->image_url,
    'format'=> ['image',['width'=>'100','height'=>'100']],
],
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49045770/edit) your answer to explain why this piece of code answers the question.